# Is there anyway to email me when someone access my goo.gl shorten link?

Tags: goo.gl

I have a shortened link and I want to be warned when someone access it.
I searched over the internet but cannot found anything.

Comment: Nope.  Make the link unique by appending ?from=googl for example, detect this in the target page and act upon it there.

Comment: I just found this page.

https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#url_analytics

cannot we make some script to check the  "shortUrlClicks": "3227" function every x minutes ou hours?

Thank you so much !!